# Position Bootstrap badge on menu

Tags: css, laravel-blade

I'm trying to position my Bootstrap badge like the next picture:

[image]

But this is what I'm getting:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Or what can I add to my CSS?

This is my code:

```
<div class="col-md">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ route('user.cart') }}"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning">{{ Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart')->totalQty : '' }}</span>
  <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
<div class="col-md">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ route('user.cart') }}">
    <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning count-notif">{{ Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart')->totalQty : '' }}</span>
    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

add this in css

```
.count-notif{
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin-left:-15px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  font-size:13px;
}

.badge-warning{
  padding:3px;
}
```